# Numeric edittext loses focus after first input in listview

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have multiple edittexts in my listview, numeric and normal. When I click on a numeric it gets the focus and pops up the keypad but after I enter 1 number, it loses its focus and I have to click on it again to enter more numbers. Is there a way to keep focus so I can enter more numbers? My normal edittext works perfectly.

I have already tried with adjustpan and different keyboard modes.

edittext code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEditTextItem"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="5"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Listview code:

```
         <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorCard"
            android:groupIndicator="@null">
        </ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, after debugging the currentFocus i found out that the listview onExpand() took the focus away, setting editText.requestfocus() after returned the focus to the edittext.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the listview : you have to add the following to manifest in the listview activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and the following to listview

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Comment: Tried it, still loses it focus after entering the first number

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but my EditText is not in any ListView. It is simply inside  several nested LinearLayouts and also looses its focus as for . What fixed my issue was to add TextChangedListener for this EditText in activity code and in onTextChanged I set:

```
EditText.requestFocusFromTouch()
```